# Make child container occupy height of parent container [React Native]

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I made a `<View>` object in react native containing, in a row, multiple `<View>` objects that contain text objects.

When the text is more than 1 line, the text containers do not expand to fill the parent component and it looks funny.

Screenshot:

[image]

This is the style code:

```
  bigContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    // flexDirection: 'row'
  },

  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingRight: 0,
    borderRightWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 0,
    borderColor: 'rbga(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 7,
    paddingBottom: 7,
    overflow: 'hidden'
  },

  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
```

Please help, I do not understand why this happens since I have `flex: 1` and my research has not helped me. Thanks !!

UPDATE: SOLVED: I forgot that `<TouchableOpacity>`, the container that encloses the text container, also behaves like a flexbox

Comment: EDIT: SOLVED: I forgot that `<TouchableOpacity>` behaves as a flexbox !!

Comment: bigContainer: { alignItems: 'stretch'}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In React Native flex works a bit differently, as it only accepts a single number. This is because of the [`Yoga` layout engine facebook uses](https://github.com/facebook/yoga)

`flex: 1` does not mean "grow as much as you need to". When you assign a group of child components that property, what you're essentially saying is that each element with the `flex: 1` property should take up as much space as each other element. Think of `flex: 1` as assigning a ratio. If you have 1 element with no siblings, it will attempt to fill all available space. If you have 4 elements and they are all siblings, and they are all set to `flex: 1` then each will take 1/4 (25%) of the available space.

This can be manipulated as well, say you have 4 elements and 3 of them are set to `flex: 1`. You can set the 4th to `flex: 2`. That 4th element will now use twice as much space as the other components (40% of available space as opposed to 20%). Flex can also be set to a negative number, which means it will shrink to it's min height and width when needed.

This behavior is pretty much identical to how the `flex-grow` property works in CSS. If you want to manipulate the initial size of a flex container without respect to it's siblings, you should use the `flex-basis` (`flexBasis` in react) property. `flexBasis: content` will resize the container based on it's content. `flexBasis` also accepts a number, if you would like to manually set the initial width of your containers.